# Android library not building

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying to create a test library from android application. I followed official google instruction, but when I'm trying to build, nothing happens. Android Studio does not create aar or apk file. Here is my gradle file and structure. Why it not building?

[image]

Comment: Care to share some logs or something?

Comment: I have no logs. Its just not building apk or sometings. When I'm pressing, It's just do nothing

Comment: On the toolbar, next to the hammer, see the android logo with that x? There's the problem